# Adding a Back button to a iOS app in Titanium Appcelerator without TabGroup or NavBar

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I'm developing with Titanium Appcelerator for iOS. I would like to manage manually a 'back' button using the properties of window, that can set a left and right buttons.

I'm trying with this code:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
win.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
var b = Titanium.UI.createButton({title:'Back'});
win.setLeftNavButton(b);
b.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
    win.close();
  });
```

But no button is showed.

Comment: if you are not using tabGroup or navBar then `win.setLeftNavButton(b);` this code will not work because its specific for navBar and tabGroup. If you want the back button then give its top, left property and directly add it to the window.

Comment: Make your own custom header view with title,left and right button (if needed) and export that view in your windows. In this way you have full control on the buttons and the UI of header as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Swanand is right but i want to add some more thing that if you use modal property of window to open then also you can use setLeftNavButton method to set button in navigation bar but if you do not want to use tab group or navigation group or even modal property then you need to add that button in window with left,top,width and height property.

You can use below example....

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
win.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
var b = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        title:'Back',
        width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        top : 10,
        left : 10
        });
win.add(b);
```